# Capturing either one or other group with regex

Tags: regex

I have a hard time figuring out if this is possible with regexes. I have the following string (*The original string is longer, it is a json string*):

```
... "WorkstationName":"WS-8300E-007","IpAddress":"192.10.10.10" ...
```

And I want to catch the **IpAddress** or, if the IpAddress does not exists, the **WorkstationName**

```
# IPADDR = 192.10.10.10
... "WorkstationName":"WS-8300E-007","IpAddress":"192.10.10.10" ...

# IPADDR = WS-8300E-007
... "WorkstationName":"WS-8300E-007","IpAddress":"-" ...
```

I have tried several patterns:

- conditional lookahead
- capturing a backreference
- other tries I forgot

but without success, I need to capture the pattern in a named group `(?P<ipaddr>)` so that the output can be processed by other software.

The latest regex I ended up with is :

```
(?:("WorkstationName":)(?=.*IpAddress":"-"))?(?(1)(?:"([^"]+)")?|.*IpAddress":"([^"]+")?)(?P<ipaddr>(?(2)\2|\3))
```

So, basically, I do:

- check if "WorkstationName" is followed, at some point by an invalid ip ("-")
- if it is, capture the workstation name in **\1**
- if the group **\1** exists, capture the workstation name
- otherwise capture the ip address

The hard time I'm having is using the named group, I have already suceeded in capturing everything in 2 groups, but I absolutely need to be on the same group depending on the string.

**I cannot use JSON parsers**

Comment: What stops you from using simple `(IpAddress|WorkstationName)`?

Comment: that was just so simple that I didn't think about it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^.*(?:IpAddress(?!":"-)|WorkstationName)":"(?P<ipaddr>[^"]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/kn2HKmRkFeAyaDaJ)

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uU7eR7/1)

Comment: I just feel so idiot, the solution was simple enough that I have not thinked about it ! thank you this is exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
~^.*"(?:IpAddress":"\K[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|WorkstationName":"\K[^"]*)(?=")~m
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/qN1zF7/1)

Since it starts with `.*` (a greedy quantifier) the alternation is tested from the end of the line to the beginning and the first successful branch wins.